# innerHTML example: With user input it doesn´t work, why?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have this working code, with an example of innerHTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ejemplo de innerHTML
function cambiarColor(){
    var oldHTML = document.getElementById('para').innerHTML;
    var newHTML = "<span style='color:lightgreen'>" + oldHTML + "</span>";
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = newHTML;
}
</script>
<p id='para'>Hola <b id='nombre'>gente</b> </p> 
<input type='button' onclick='cambiarColor()' value='Change Text'/>
```

But then I wanted to change color using some user input.
My problem is that it doesn´t work. It shows (in the color the user chooses) the word "undefined". I´ve used the console and I understand that "mensaje" variable is not defined? Why is that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ejemplo de innerHTML con User Input
function cambiarColorUser(){
    mensaje=document.getElementById('clase').value;
    nuevoColor=document.getElementById('nuevoColor').value;
    mensajeCambiado="<span style='color:"+ nuevoColor +";'>"+ mensaje +"</span>";
    document.getElementById('clase').innerHTML=mensajeCambiado;
}
</script>
<p id='clase'><h1>Mensaje que cambia de color</h1> </p>
<input type="text" id="nuevoColor">
<input type='button' onclick='cambiarColorUser()' value='Cambia el Color!'/>
```

### UPDATE

After reading your replies, I´ve updated the code, that still won´t work (http://jsfiddle.net/vjze5/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ejemplo de innerHTML con User Input
function cambiarColorUser(){
    var mensaje=document.getElementById('clase').innerHTML;
    var nuevoColor=document.getElementById('nuevoColor').value;
    var mensajeCambiado="<span style='color:"+ nuevoColor +";'>"+ mensaje +"</span>";
    document.getElementById('clase').innerHTML=mensajeCambiado;
}
</script>
<p id='clase'><h1>Mensaje que cambia de color</h1> </p>
<input type="text" id="nuevoColor">
<input type='button' onclick='cambiarColorUser()' value='Cambia el Color!'/>
```

***Note: If I type "red" inside the text input, and open the console in Chrome, and type "cambiarColorUser()" it replies "undefined".***

Comment: So, for me, here **[it works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M7zHa/)**?

Comment: @DavidThomas - it's the second code block that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of your code:

```
mensaje=document.getElementById('clase').value;
```

`.value` is for some form controls, not for paragraph tags.

Perhaps you meant for that line of code to be:

```
mensaje=document.getElementById('clase').innerHTML;
```

---

Also, all local variables (variables intended to be used only within a funnction) should be declared with `var` in front of them.  This isn't actually causing a problem in your current code, but is a very bad practice and will cause problems in the future.