# text of input field is not printing while print using window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have following html layout:

```
Please fill up this form carefully:
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print'); return false;" value="Print" />
<div id="print">
  <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="user_name" value="" />
     <input type="text" name="address" value="" />
     <input type="text" name="date" value="14-06-2015" />
     <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
</div>
```

and the printDiv('print') function in the head section of that html page:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

but while printing the form after filled-up, it is not showing the text of input fields that an user entered in the input box. but the predefined text (here the date field) of the input field of the same form is printing as usual.

How can I rewrite the javascript function so that it will print the text of input fields aslo?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? You want them to be able to fill out the form, then print it, and submit it?

Comment: Seth MrClaine, yes if an user want to print out before submitting. Please keep in mind that this is only for showing the problem I am facing. This is not important why an user want to print the form before printing or a page may show the submitted form and the user can print from there. This is a test case.

Comment: you can loop the inputs and `input.setAttribute("value", input.value)` before using innerHTML if you want the current values to show up.

Answer (score 4):

That's because innerHTML does not reflect changes by the user in input fields. See [innerHTML example: With user input it doesn´t work, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610299). A better solution is to use a
[CSS stylesheet](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) to control the printable content.

```
@media print {
    body {display:none};
    #print {display: block};
}
```

I am on a phone so I can't test it, you may need to update your HTML and CSS so that you don't have nested conflicting display rules

Comment: I have to use that javascript function to select content inside div for a particular purpose. I can't use hide method to hide all other contents of the page, except the div content.

Comment: Then you may need to manually copy the values of all fields into the form you have created (by setting innerHTML), and when you recreate the entire body tag. Keep in mind that recreating an entire page with innerHTML is often problematic because event handlers are lost.

Answer (score 2):

Some years later, but... i have an idea to solve this that worked for me. It's very simple:

```
$('form#myId input').bind("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr('value',val);
});
```

We only collect the input value and, in the change event, replace it with the same value that we just entered using attr(). When replacing, it's already recorded in the DOM and will be loaded when we trying to print. I don't think that more explanation is needed, it's very simple.

Regards.

Comment: This really works for me in 2021 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you are asking, but the following code will display the user inputs along with the original body if that is all you want. It does not use window.print(); though.

```
    function printDiv() {
        var printContents = document.forms[0].elements[0].value + "<br>" + document.forms[0].elements[1].value + "<br>";
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.write(printContents + originalContents);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. But I am not clear how your code will print the input text along with other text. There may be other text in printContents inside that div, such as here there is a text 'Please fill up this form carefully:'. Your code only print the form. But how can I print text of form along with all other text inside of that target div.