# Checkmark is not printing for javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello can anyone tell me why my checkmarks are not printing ?I assume The 3rd line of the Javascript code is creating the problem. Please help. I dont know much about Javascript.

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal bucket-form" id="printMe" method="get" >
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Old </label>
  <input type="checkbox"><span class="checkbox-material"></span>
  <label>New </label>
  <input type="checkbox"><span class="checkbox-material"></span>
 </div>
</form>
<br><br>
<button onclick="printDiv('printMe')">Print only the above div</button>

<script>
function printDiv(divName){
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

check my code here
https://codepen.io/Nazmulpen/pen/YeoYYE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text of input field is not printing while print using window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825983/text-of-input-field-is-not-printing-while-print-using-window-print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print` media css to achieve this. You can assign a class, say `notToPrint` to all the elements you want to exclude in the print preview and print. Then using `print` media css you can hide them and you get only the elements that you wish to print.

```js
function printDiv(){
 window.print();
}
```

```css
@media print
{
.notToPrint { visibility: hidden; }
#printMe { visibility: visible; }
}
```

```html
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal bucket-form" id="printMe" method="get" >
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Old </label>
  <input type="checkbox"><span class="checkbox-material"></span>
  <label>New </label>
  <input type="checkbox"><span class="checkbox-material"></span>
</div>
</form>
<br><br>
<button onclick="printDiv()">Print only the above div</button>

<div class='notToPrint'>This will not be printed</div>
```

Also here is the updated link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZjYdN)