# Print function in angular is not showing text inside inputs and angular material style

Tags: angular, angular-material, media, angular6

I need to print specific part of a component in angular. The component html is built with angular material.

When I use the following:

```
print(){
    let divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint').innerHTML;
    let newWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    newWindow.document.open();
    newWindow.document.write(`
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="./login.component.css" type="text/css" media="print">
          <style>
            @media print {
              .noprint {display:none;}
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${divToPrint}   
        </body>
      </html>
    `);
    newWindow.document.close();
  }
```

If there is text inside inputs, the printable window does not show them.

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30826042/3922727) on stackexchange, where the user said:

> That's because innerHTML does not reflect changes by the user in input
>   fields.

And we should add print media.

I already added the @media style and nothing happened as the inputs still empty.
Please take note that I am getting the values from database.

The other problem is that all material style are not shown either. So, an input is shown as basic html input instead of it's related mat-input style.

Comment: That document you're loading does not use Angular - it's a plain HTML document that doesn't reference anything other than the `login.component.css` file - which might not even exist after compilation/deploy

Comment: So even if we attached material theme inside the style are of print code ?

Comment: You're opening a popup window that doesn't inherit anything from it's "parent". You're probably better off using something like [dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)...

Comment: @fredrik can I take the data given from database to this dialog too ? Because data are being connected to the url login_id.

Comment: Read the `Sharing data` section of the documentation.