# Window.print() input text in form - javascript, angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, printing

I have the following html code which consists of a form, containing different types of fields:

```
        <div class="card-body" id="print">
          <form [formGroup]="form">
                  <div class="text-muted" *ngFor="let field of category.fields">
                    <h5>
                      {{ field.name }}
                    </h5>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="field.type === 'text' || field.type === 'number'" >
                      <input
                        formControlName="{{ field.key }}"
                        type="{{ field.type }}"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="{{ field.name }}"
                      />
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container *ngIf="field.type === 'textarea'">
                      <textarea
                        formControlName="{{ field.key }}"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Comments"
                      ></textarea>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container *ngIf="field.type === 'date'">
                      <div
                        class="input-group"
                      >
                        <input
                          formControlName="{{ field.key }}"
                          ngbDatepicker
                          #dateField="ngbDatepicker"
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                        />
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <div
                            class="input-group-text"
                            (click)="dateField.toggle()"
                          >
                            <i
                              class="fa fa-calendar"
                              style="cursor: pointer;"
                            ></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container *ngIf="field.type === 'dropdown'">
                      <select
                        class="custom-select"
                        formControlName="{{ field.key }}"
                      >
                        <option [ngValue]="null">
                          Select {{ field.name }}
                        </option>
                        <option
                          *ngFor="let option of field.options"
                          [ngValue]="option.value"
                        >
                          {{ option.label }}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                      <br />
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container
                      *ngIf="field.type === 'checkbox_multi_choice'"
                    >
                      <div
                        class="form-check mb-1"
                        *ngFor="let option of field.options"
                      >
                        <p-checkbox
                          class="mr-1"
                          [formControl]="form.controls[field.key]"
                          [value]="option.value"
                        ></p-checkbox>
                        <label class="form-check-label"
                          >{{ option.label }}</label
                        >
                      </div>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container *ngIf="field.type === 'radio'">
                      <div
                        class="form-check"
                        *ngFor="let option of field.options"
                      >
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          [value]="option.value"
                          formControlName="{{ field.key }}"
                          class="form-check-input"
                        />
                        <label class="form-check-label"
                          >{{ option.label }}</label
                        >
                      </div>
                    </ng-container>
                  </div>
                </ng-container>
              </ng-container>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

I am trying to window.print this form using the following function:

```
  download() {
    var printContents = document.getElementById("print").innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    location.reload();
  }
```

It works ok, apart from not all the input field values are being displayed in the print. Only the 'checkbox_multi_choice' values are showing.

After some research it seems window.print() does not capture input field values, so is there a way around this? How can i get the values to appear in the boxes when i window.print() it?

EDIT!!!

Thanks to @majusebetter, i have got the text boxes showing, however it still isn't showing the contents of the radio buttons. Below is the code so far, can anyone help me with how to edit this to get the radio buttons working?

```
  download() {
    let element: any = document.getElementById("print");
    const iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe"));

    iframe.style.display = "none";

    const idoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    idoc.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML;
    idoc.body.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

    const inputs = element.querySelectorAll("input");
    const printInputs = idoc.body.querySelectorAll("input");

    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      printInputs[i].value = inputs[i].value;
    }

    const selects = element.querySelectorAll("select");
    const printSelects = idoc.body.querySelectorAll("select");

    for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
      printSelects[i].value = selects[i].value;
    }

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      iframe.contentWindow.print();
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: This question has answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825983/text-of-input-field-is-not-printing-while-print-using-window-print

Comment: @majusebetter thanks, but i'm struggling to get that to fit my example. As my field inputs could be anything (as i am looping through an array to get them)

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Have you tried looping through them and applying the same method as the linked suggestion. Give it a try and then come back and update your question with more information.

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Updated my answer below. Now it also sets the `checked` state of the `input` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the HTML to be printed to an `IFRAME` element along with the styles and then copy the input/select values from the source elements to the target elements in the `IFRAME`:

```
print(element: HTMLElement): void {
    const iframe = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement('iframe'));

    iframe.style.display = 'none';

    const idoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    idoc.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML;
    idoc.body.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

    const inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input');
    const printInputs = idoc.body.querySelectorAll('input');

    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        printInputs[i].value = inputs[i].value;
        printInputs[i].checked = inputs[i].checked;
    }

    const selects = element.querySelectorAll('select');
    const printSelects = idoc.body.querySelectorAll('select');

    for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        printSelects[i].value = selects[i].value;
    }

    window.setTimeout(() => {
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
        document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    }, 1000);
}
```

**EDIT**
Added code for radio buttons:

`printInputs[i].checked = inputs[i].checked;`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working for the text boxes, however the radio buttons are still aren't showing, is there a way to get them working too?

Comment: You're welcome. Updated my answer - now it should also set the `checked` state of radio buttons / checkboxes.